# How to capture p and ul tags without grabbing ul's nested tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

With Nokogiri, I am trying to obtain all the "first" level `p` and `ul` HTML tags and having a little difficulty.

For example, here's the HTML that I'm working with

```
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out&nbsp;</strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<ul>
    <li>One thing here.
        <ul>
            <li>One more thing</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Another thing here</li>
</ul>
<p>
    <br>
</p>
<ul>
    <li>nothing</li>
</ul>
<p>Some more text.</p>
```

I'm wanting to grab all the paragraphs and all of the unordered lists. Because the unordered lists aren't surrounded with the `p` tag, I have to grab for those as well using the following example:

```
#data = the HTML above
html = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
html.xpath("//p | //ul").each do |p|
 # some code
end
```

The problem is that the output of `html.xpath("//p | //ul")` looks like this:

```
<p><strong>Just testing <em>something</em> out </strong>over here.</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that contains bullets though:</p>
<ul>
    <li>One thing here.
        <ul>
            <li>One more thing</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Another thing here</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>One more thing</li>
</ul>
<p>
    <br>
</p>
<ul>
    <li>nothing</li>
</ul>
<p>Some more text.</p>
```

As you can see there, `One more thing` repeats itself because it's one of the nested `ul` tags inside of `ul`. Because of that, my code ends up doing the same thing twice to this text.

So what I'm looking for is to "exclude" nested tags if it's the same of the parent so that when I run `html.xpath("//p | //u")` or something similar, it looks at the `ul` tag and just treats it all as one element in the xpath output array

Is there a way to do this with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to select first level element of certain name using XPath :

```
//target_element[not(ancestor::target_element)]
```

So for your specific case the XPath would be as follow :

```
//p[not(ancestor::p)] | //ul[not(ancestor::ul)]
```